# JQuery Tabs Custom CSS

Tags: jquery

I need to apply Custom CSS for jquery tabs....
I have two Jquery tab panels on single View...How to apply diffrent CSS for both Tab panels

Css for Selected and hover and default

Please give me suggestion

Thanks
Narasimha

Answer (score 1):

use a containing element with a different class to specify the styles for the particular one!